# Objective-C Reload issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, plist

I have a Graph with numbers of entries in it.It loads the data by using the `For` loop from plist..means one by one..now I want in such a way that if data read from that is `greater than 6` then should take `substringToIndex:2` else `substringToIndex:6`

but problem is: Data is in plist and fetching it one by one..and i want if `greater than 6` then it should be `substringToIndex:2`for whole values not for the next values.but how can i reload data if it is more than 6 to make whole values of `substringToIndex:2`

**code**

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {

  int l=0;
  NSMutableArray *Array=[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[self readFromPlistForOneWeek]];
  NSMutableArray *items = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

  for (id object in [Array reverseObjectEnumerator]){

    if ([object isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]])
    {
        NSDictionary *objDict = (NSDictionary *)object;

        //problem part below 
           l++;
        if(l>6){
              str1=[str1 substringToIndex:2];
              tempItemi.isPercentage=YES;
              tempItemi.yValue=f;
              tempItemi.width=10;
              tempItemi.name=str1;      
              [items addObject: tempItemi];
          } else{
              str1 =[str1 substringToIndex:6];
              tempItemi.isPercentage=YES;
              tempItemi.yValue=f;
              tempItemi.width=10;
              tempItemi.name=str1;
              [items addObject: tempItemi];
          }
     }
```

This gives me output iike this

[image: enter the image] 
.

**here if values are more than 6 it should take subStringToIndex:2 for all ..not only for more than 6(not for last 2 in image)**

Comment: What is l? What should be more than 6?

Comment: I forget to increment it my code.check now its `l++;` and l is to count the values...and if plist values are more than 6 it should take subStringToIndex:2

Comment: Why dont you just check `if ([Array count] > 6)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont have to use `if (l>6)`. You can directly use,

```
if ([Array count] > 6)
```

The above code will not work since you are incrementing it in the loop and check it while incrementing. You need to check against the count of the array.